# Bigquery importing map's json data into a table

Tags: json, nested, google-bigquery

I have a json file which has data from a pojo, which is basically

```
String
Map<String, Set<OBJ>>
```

=> where object has

```
int
int 
string
timestamp
```

Here is a sample row: 
{"key":"123qwe123","mapData":{"3539":[{"id":36,"type":1,"os":"WINDOWS","lastSeenDate":"2015-06-03 22:46:38 UTC"}],"16878":[{"id":36,"type":1,"os":"WINDOWS","lastSeenDate":"2015-06-03 22:26:34 UTC"}],"17312":[{"id":36,"type":1,"os":"WINDOWS","lastSeenDate":"2015-06-03 22:26:48 UTC"}]}}

I tried to do following schema, but thats not working:

> ```
> [
> {
>      "name" : "key",
>      "type" : "string"
> },
> {
>     "name" : "mapData",
>     "type" : "record",
>     "mode": "repeated",
> "fields": [
> {
>     "name": "some_id",
>    "type": "record",
>     "mode" : "repeated",
>     "fields" : [
>     {
>             "name": "id",
>             "type": "integer",
>             "mode": "nullable"
>     },
>     {
>             "name": "type",
>             "type": "integer",
>             "mode": "nullable"
>     },
>     {
>             "name": "os",
>             "type": "string",
>             "mode": "nullable"
>     },
>     {
>             "name": "lastSeenDate",
>             "type": "timestamp",
>             "mode": "nullable"
>     }
>     ]
> }
> ] } ]
> ```

When i run i get: repeated record must be imported as a JSON array 
I know something is up with schema but not figured out yet.

Comment: The first int in the object is a string, isn't it?

Comment: ok, let me edit it. Originally map's key was an int but in json its string now.

Comment: problem is map's key which is a string, does not have a name to associate in json schema, so i just tried with "name": "some_id", but thats not working

Comment: The entry with "some_id" looks confusing. Where is it in the json example?

Comment: yes, there where is my confusion. The 3539 from json sample provided, is basically the 'key' of the map, and that has no 'name'. so in json it comes just as "3539" and I am getting confused on how to make schema out of that.

Comment: Put the name "some_id" into the json to make it conform, can't you?

Comment: if i manually try adding fully qualified name to map key and values, then it's working. Thanks for suggestion. Now i will figure out some custom de-serializer for my pojo that will generate proper json.  This worked: {"key":"123qwe123","mapData":[{"some_id": "3539", "sample_data" :[{"id":36,"type":1,"os":"WINDOWS","lastSeenDate":"2015-06-03 22:46:38 UTC"}]}, ....