# Converting Protobuf Datatypes map<string , google.protobuf.Any> to BigQuery Datatypes

Tags: google-bigquery, protocol-buffers

I'm wondering if we can convert Protobuf datatypes of map to bigquery schema datatypes. I've tried to search relevant issue and found this issue [1]. However it's seems like I still don't find the answer.

[1] [Bigquery importing map's json data into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150177/bigquery-importing-maps-json-data-into-a-table)

Comment: can you tell us more about the context/

Comment: you should be able to break protobuf map datatype into key value pars? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#backwards-compatibility